# Rails how to show flash messages after respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, flash-message

In active admin, I have to override devise password controller to show error when the password token is expired. By default, it doesn't show any errors if the token is expired. below is the method I am overriding

```
    # PUT /resource/password
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
        flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
        set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message(:notice, :updated_not_active) if is_flashing_format?
      end
      respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

If `resource.errors.empty?` returns false it does not set any flash messages.
In order to throw an error exception, I did the following:

```
ActiveAdmin::Devise::PasswordsController.class_eval do
  def update
    super
    if resource.errors.any?
      flash[:notice] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end
  end
end
```

With the above code, errors are now visible but not on the same page load. It however, shows in the next view. It also works fine if I copy the code from devise password controller and just add the flash message in the else block before 'respond_with' But I don't like that approach.

Is there a way to show flash message without copying the whole method from the devise controller?

Comment: Did you try with flash.now?

Comment: flash.now does not show any error at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second line of the update action there's the following:

```
yield resource if block_given?
```

This means that you can pass a block to this method, like so:

```
def update
  super do |resource|
    if resource.errors.any?
      flash[:notice] = resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**This does work also**

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])

 respond_to do |format|
 if @user.save
  flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
  format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
  format.xml { render xml: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
else
  format.html { render action: "new" }
  format.xml { render xml: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity           }
 end
 end
 end
```